# Openlayers 6 delay interaction

Tags: javascript, typescript, openlayers-6

I want to implement a dragBox and a dragPan features on the map for touch screens, I limit the dragPan condition with two fingers, and the dragBox with one finger. However, the dragBox will still appear when users use two fingers on the screen. I would like to set a delay on the dragBox event so it could correctly detect the number of fingers on the screen. Is this possible?

```
  this.dragPanOptions = {
        condition: function (event) {
            return this.getPointerCount() === 2 || platformModifierKeyOnly(event);
        },
    };
    this.dragBoxOptions = {
        condition: function (event) {
            return this.getPointerCount() === 1 && noModifierKeys (event);
        },
    };
```

I tried to extends the DragBox class in order to implement my own handleDownEvent function with delay, but it seems I cannot access the private members.

Another way is re-implement the whole DragBox class with a delay option, but some class like RenderBox does not exist. But I don't want download the whole library from github.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @OrAssayag I have update the question, I want to delay the condition function of dragBoxOptions, but it seems impossible